# Can a diode prevent backwards current flow from a constant current source?

Tags: diodes, battery-charging, constant-current, nimh, alkaline

I'm trying to make a AA battery replacement battery for a vintage computer because its actual battery has gone bad. Its of the NiMH type and I'm pretty sure those are charged with a constant current. I want to make sure that my alkaline batteries don't get accidentally charged if the AC adapter were to be plugged in. Would a diode prevent the constant current charger from charging my AA batteries?

Answer (score 1):

It would (for all intents and purposes - there is always some leakage). However, a more significant issue is the fact that it will also drop almost half of you AA battery voltage - and thus waste half of the energy inside the battery. There are two options to mitigate this:

Battery protection circuits with some form of switch, such as a mosfet: These exist and use a circuit that will open a mosfet when power is applied from the output.

Alternatively, you could just use a NiMH battery and allow the system to charge it.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage must be the same  ( within 20% est.) and the current is likely to be less than a few mA which will not create significant damage.

I recently repaired an old le Croy DSO that someone had replaced a 2.4V 2S NiCd pack with a Lithium 3.6V primary CR2 cell.  It failed to work due to a faulty plated thru hole. I fixed that then the RTC worked, but then it started to fail booting until I examined the schematics to see it was used in areas with 3.3V logic and 3.6V could be latchup problem.  SO I inserted an LED to measure current by intensity. It was barely visible (<1mA) and the 1.6V drop to 2V was too much for the RTC to function, but it booted.  So then I replaced the series LED with a Si diode in series with the 3.6V battery to get 3V and then it worked for RTC and booted successfully.

### Moral of the story.

Don't change backup battery voltage and chemistry unless you know the implications.